# Is it possible to impose an upper bound (super X) on a named Generic type?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, super

Suppose I have the following static method and interface (List is java.util.List). Note that the static method enforces a "super Foo" on the wildcard type of the list.

```
public class StaticMethod {
   public static void doSomething(List<? super Foo> fooList) {
      ...
   }
}

public interface MyInterface<T> {
   public void aMethod(List<T> aList);
}
```

I would like to be able to add a class which implements the interface using the static method as follows:

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
   public void aMethod(List<T> aList) {
     StaticMethod.doSomething(aList);
   }
}
```

This obviously won't compile because T does not have the "super Foo" constraint. However, I can't see any way of adding the "super Foo" constraint. For example - the following is not legal:

```
public class MyClass<T super Foo> implements MyInterface<T> {
   public void aMethod(List<T> aList) {
     StaticMethod.doSomething(aList);
   }
}
```

Is there any way of solving this problem - ideally without altering `StaticMethod` or `MyInterface`?

Comment: I assume you can't require that `MyClass` implements `MyInterface<Long>`? Would work but doesn't quite get at what you want.

Comment: FYI: Angelika Langer covers lower bounds for types [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107)

Comment: @McDowell That's helpful. Interesting that lower bounds are allowed on wilcards. I need to think this through a bit more - whether this example provides a counterexample to Angelika Langer's argument

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I think lower bounding is the problem here, because you have to know about the actual class that fits the bound when you refer to it... you can't use inheritance.

Here's a usage that compiles, but notice that I need to name the actual class that is a super of Foo:

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
}

class Foo extends SomeOtherClass
{
}

class StaticMethod
{
    public static <T> void doSomething(List<? super Foo> fooList)
    {
    }
}

interface MyInterface<T>
{
    public void aMethod(List<T> aList);
}

class MySpecificClass implements MyInterface<SomeOtherClass>
{
    public void aMethod(List<SomeOtherClass> aList)
    {
        StaticMethod.doSomething(aList);
    }
}
```

Comments?

p.s. I like the question :)

Comment: This clarifies the problem a bit - now MyClass is no longer generic (as you said) it requires the upper bound to be explicitly specified. Not quite a solution, but I'm not sure a solution is possible in the Java language as it stands. Oh well, I might have to live with MyClass not being generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `aList` contains objects that can be safely cast to `<? super Foo>`, then you can do:

```
public static class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    @Override
    public void aMethod(List<T> aList) {
        StaticMethod.doSomething((List<? super Foo>) aList);
    }
}
```

See the complete and working example: http://ideone.com/fvm67